# Pictures being placed by macro slowly gaining "underlap" as they are placed?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro, and while there's still a weird error I keep getting, open on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068529/macro-from-excel-2003-doesnt-work-in-excel-2007?noredirect=1#comment41164642_26068529), my current question is about the placing of the images.

[This Small Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Urb.jpg) shows the pictures after being placed in the picture cells. The farther down you go, the worse the "underlap" gets, and I cannot figure out why.

The relevant VBA script is:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(i + 13)
        Debug.Print "Cell " & rng.Address & " | Cell Range: " & rng.Top & " " & rng.Left & " " & rng.MergeArea.Height & " " & rng.MergeArea.Width
       .LockAspectRatio = False
       .Top = Int(rng.Top + 1)
       .Left = Int(rng.Left)
       .Height = rng.MergeArea.Height
       .Width = rng.MergeArea.Width
        Debug.Print "Picture: " & .Top & " " & .Left & " " & .Height & " " & .Width
        
        End With
```

To head off some of the comments I anticipate:  Yes, `rng` is set. It's set immediately before this. The console output below shows that. Yes, the corresponding shape is correct - there are 13 "shapes" on this sheet from the template to begin with.

Some console output for the `Debug.Print` calls.

```
Cell $M$134 | Cell Range: 2038.5 519 180 243.75
Picture: 2039 519.0001 180 243.75
Cell $A$150 | Cell Range: 2278.5 0 180 243.75
Picture: 2279 7.874016E-05 180 243.75
Cell $G$150 | Cell Range: 2278.5 259.5 180 243.75
Picture: 2279 259.0001 180 243.75
```

*Small Note* the `.Top=Int(Top.rng+1)` and `.Left = Int(rng.Left)` calls were added in hopes they would alleviate some of the error of the "underlap" - they didn't, I just haven't deleted them.

How is it that the picture cells and the pictures themselves can have the same measurements and placement values, but still not be aligned?

## Solved

One of the comments suggested setting the Zoom to regular, and that fixed it. I don't know why, but I'm glad I can move on from this issue.

Comment: I recommend not to round or `INT()` ... the delta is very small and only due to floating point operations

Comment: Try changing the page zoom to 100%.

Comment: remove int, as it uses decimals also for placing. (remove +1 also)

Comment: Even without the `Int()` calls to the `.Top` and `.Left`, the cells still have the underlap, just that now there are absolutely no differences in the logged properties. I just don't get how it could say it has the same position, height, and width, yet still be off.

Comment: @Rory, I just saw your comment. It fixed it.. but why?

Comment: Blame Microsoft? Blame Microsoft. Damn you Microsoft!